# Exchange receive connectors throttling- does it enforced for local connection?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

Probably lame question but I'm not very well familiar with Exchange email flow (2010/13/16).I know there are throttling policies we can configure on receive connector level, in particular MaxMessageRate limit. I recently was trying to reproduce a scenario where app which does email sending through Exchange gets throttled by this limit. I set Message Rate limit to 1 on all connectors but my app was not throttled. Am I right that this is because my app is installed locally on the same box with Exchange or I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "local" connections within Exchange 2010 and higher. Due to the architecture of Exchange the hub transport role is separate from the other roles and all email is subject to any restrictions applied at that level.

After making a throttling change, did you restart the MS Exchange Transport service?

Comment: No I din't restart Transport Service - will check this